# recursion in python with example

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, recursion

i had question regarding the recursion method in python.i have the below program:

houses = ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]

```
    def deliver_presents_recursively(houses):

     if len(houses) == 1:
        house = houses[0]
        print("Delivering presents to", house)
    else:
        mid = len(houses) // 2
        first_half = houses[:mid]
        second_half = houses[mid:]

        # Divides his work among two elves
        deliver_presents_recursively(first_half)
        deliver_presents_recursively(second_half)


    print("End of ifElse statement",houses)

deliver_presents_recursively(houses)
```

and the following output is shown:

```
Delivering presents to Eric's house
    End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house"]
    Delivering presents to Kenny's house
    End of ifElse statement ["Kenny's house"]
    End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house"]
    Delivering presents to Kyle's house
    End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house"]
    Delivering presents to Stan's house
    End of ifElse statement ["Stan's house"]
    End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
    End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]

            i had the doubt like after all the if statement are printed

            Delivering presents to Eric's house

            Delivering presents to Kenny's house

            Delivering presents to Kyle's house

            Delivering presents to Stan's house

            and the last ifelse printout gets printed 
            "End of ifElse statement ["Stan's house"]"

            then the program should come to the end. also there is no while loop present then how does the program print the last 2 statements

            End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
            End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem here. It's also unclear what your question is? You wrote a recursive function and it's working - the output is correct.

Comment: i want to understand the output...how the last 2 lines are getting printed End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
            End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]                                       the program should end after               "End of ifElse statement ["Stan's house"]"    since now the houses variable contains only 1 item.it prints the  final if statement and then comes out of the if else .. so how does it display the last two lines....Probably i am misinterpreting recursion...

Comment: imagine that you commented out the 2 recursive calls to deliver_presents_recursively(). Think about what the output would be in that case and I think you'll understand...

Answer (score 0):

Your function first completes the work, and then it displays its argument. If I represent levels of recursion with indentation, here's what's happening:

```
        Delivering presents to Eric's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house"]
        Delivering presents to Kenny's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Kenny's house"]
    End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house"]
        Delivering presents to Kyle's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house"]
        Delivering presents to Stan's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Stan's house"]
    End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
```

if you add `print("Starting delivery to",houses)` at the beginning, then your output would be:

```
Starting delivery to ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
    Starting delivery to ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house"]
        Starting delivery to ["Eric's house"]
            Delivering presents to Eric's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house"]
        Starting delivery to ["Kenny's house"]
            Delivering presents to Kenny's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Kenny's house"]
    End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house"]
    Starting delivery to ["Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
        Starting delivery to ["Kyle's house"]
            Delivering presents to Kyle's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house"]
        Starting delivery to ["Stan's house"]
            Delivering presents to Stan's house
        End of ifElse statement ["Stan's house"]
    End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]
```

(Indentation added for clarity)

Comment: my question is how these last 2 statements are getting displayed. From where the call is being made for                                                                                               
     End of ifElse statement ["Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]    and           
End of ifElse statement ["Eric's house", "Kenny's house", "Kyle's house", "Stan's house"]                                                                                                                          
 the program should end after  End of ifElse statement ["Stan's house"]